# Why can the input.val() not be saved as global variable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, scope

I'm making multiple mapping API calls using the value of the input field (which is a postcode) and passing this as an argument for the API URL. I am also saving the postcode to localStorage to use for displaying purposes elsewhere.

When I set `var userPostalCode = $('#input').val()` as a global variable, nothing seems to work. I've even placed an `event.preventDefault()` on my click handler function to try to circumvent this. However, when I set the variable scoped to the function, it works. The issue here is, this isn't DRY whatsoever as I have to repeat the same line for each API call.

How can I a) make this DRY and b) can you please explain why I can't have it as a global variable? Abstracted code below for context:

```
// Fires call to all API functions and renders page
myBtn.click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Runs mapping functions
  firstAPICall();
  secondAPICall()
  saveToLocalStorage()
});

function firstAPICall() {
  var userPostalCode = $('#input').val();
  var FIRST_URL = `https://anotherwebsite.com/query=${userPostalCode}&limit=6&api_key=${API_KEY}`;

  $.ajax({
    url: FIRST_URL,
    method: "GET"
  }).then(function(response) {
    // Code block
  });
};

function secondAPICall() {
  var userPostalCode = $('#input').val();
  var SECOND_URL = `https://somewebsite.com/location=${userPostalCode}&api_key=${API_KEY}`;

  $.ajax({
    url: SECOND_URL,
    method: "GET"
  }).then(function(response) {
    // Code block
  });
};

function saveToLocalStorage() {
  var userPostalCode = $('#input').val();
  savedSearches.push(userPostalCode);
  localStorage.setItem("zipCode", JSON.stringify(savedSearches));
};
```

Comment: You appear to have given us the code that works, instead of the code that you need help with.  Can you please share a [mcve] of the code that *doesn't* work, so we don't have to guess at what you did wrong?   My guess is that you were trying to set `var userPostalCode = $('#input').val()` before that form field had a value, and expected the variable to update when the input field changes, which it won't; but without seeing the code that's just a guess.

Comment: (It's not clear to me what you expect the `event.preventDefault()` to be doing?  For a button click that would prevent the click event from bubbling to parent DOM elements, but that doesn't seem relevant to the issue here at all.)

Comment: When you use the `var` declaration you're creating a local variable, not assigning a global variable.

Comment: Why do you want it to be a global variable in the first place? Global variables are usually poor design. If you don't want to repeat `var userPostalCode = $("#input").val()`, do it in the click handler, then pass it as a parameter to the other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get DRY code, get the value in the click handler and pass it as a parameter.

```js
// Fires call to all API functions and renders page
myBtn.click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let userPostalCode = $('#input').val();
  // Runs mapping functions
  firstAPICall(userPostalCode);
  secondAPICall(userPostalCode)
  saveToLocalStorage(userPostalCode)
});

function firstAPICall(userPostalCode) {
  var FIRST_URL = `https://anotherwebsite.com/query=${userPostalCode}&limit=6&api_key=${API_KEY}`;

  $.ajax({
    url: FIRST_URL,
    method: "GET"
  }).then(function(response) {
    // Code block
  });
};

function secondAPICall(userPostalCode) {
  var SECOND_URL = `https://somewebsite.com/location=${userPostalCode}&api_key=${API_KEY}`;

  $.ajax({
    url: SECOND_URL,
    method: "GET"
  }).then(function(response) {
    // Code block
  });
};

function saveToLocalStorage(userPostalCode) {
  savedSearches.push(userPostalCode);
  localStorage.setItem("zipCode", JSON.stringify(savedSearches));
};
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that var creates a local variable, I was unaware of this. Also, your solution is perfect and has taught me to think outside the box.